# Golang Setting variable in global var with structs in function

Tags: go, methods

I'm a newbie to Go and I'm not seeing why the variable `tc.Duration` is not getting set as part of the global variable `Config.Core.Cron.Interval`. I added `tc.x` & `tc.y` for tests and they don't get set either. They do in the method of course but I don't see why that's not getting to the global variable.

I've cut down the code somewhat for brevity but I believe I still have everything relevant here.

```
var Config Configuration

type Configuration struct {
    Core CoreConfig
}

type CoreConfig struct {
    Cron     CronConfig
}
type CronConfig struct{ Interval TimeConfig }

type TimeConfig struct {
    String   string
    Duration *time.Duration
    x        *int
    y        int
}

func (tc *TimeConfig) setDuration(errs *int) {
    if len(tc.String) > 0 {
        // var err error
        // d := time.Duration(0)
        z := 20
        tc.x = &z
        tc.y = z
        if d, err := time.ParseDuration(tc.String); err != nil {
            logger.Error(err)
            *errs++
        } else {
            tc.Duration = &d
        }
        spew.Dump(Config.Core.Cron.Interval)
    }
}

func (c Configuration) setSpecialValueTypes() error {
    var err error

    errs := 0
    p := &errs

    // Cron
    c.Core.Cron.Interval.String = `15m`
    c.Core.Cron.Interval.setDuration(p)

    if errs > 0 {
        err = errors.New(`Errors occurred while setting special values`)
    }

    return err
}
```

Comment: setSpecialValueTypes must have a pointer receiver.

Comment: Ugh, I was looking for something very go'ish and it was just functions and pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make changes to receiver (`Configuration`) of `setSpecialValueTypes()` it has to be a **pointer receiver**. It's not possible to manipulate with a **value receiver** which copies by value and thus any modification will be local to that copy. See this part of [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4).

```golang
func (c *Configuration) setSpecialValueTypes() error { ...
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said to the comment above, Ugh! I was looking for something very go'ish and it was just functions and pointers.  Thanks.